# How do I assigned the values of an Object's > Object > Object to a variable from my controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My apologies if I'm not conveying my plead for assistance accurately.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to write entries to the `appointments` table based on certain object values after selecting the a `Book` button. There are no form values to gather in this setup. If one were to click on the `Book` button, it would gather the value of the `tech.email`, `service.name` and certain values of `service_type` then write those values to the `appointments` table.

> **The breakdown**
>
> 1. Write the value of the `tech.email` to an `appointments` table.
> 2. Write the value of the `service.name`, which is assigned to `tech`  to the `appointments` table
> 3. Write all values for `service_type`, that is assigned to a specific
>      `service` which is assigned to a specific `tech`, to the
>      `appointments` table

In short, how do I capture the instance variable for `service_type`so that I may have it in my `appointment` view for example `@service_type.name`, `@service_type.service.name`, `@service_type.service.tech`, etc...?
All this occurs inside the `tech_controller.rb`

If I were to daisy-chain the `service_type` path just to have accessibility to all of it's values. 
`@service_type = tech.first.service.first.service_type.first.`(I would like accessibility to all `service_type` values)

> **Rails Console**
>    If I were to do the following in the console.
>   `service_type = ServiceType.first`, I could to do a preferred
>   daisy-chaining method in reverse:
>
> `@service_type.service.tech.email`

What I have the following:

**Gems** 
`devise: user signup`
`cocoon: customizable nested objects`

---

**appointments.rb model** (rich join table)

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :tech
end
```

---

**tech.rb model** (db with list of techs - registered via `devise` gem)

```
    class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base

      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      has_many :appointments #unsure is this is necessary since has_many :through below
      has_many :customers, :through => :appointments
      has_many :services
      has_many :service_types      
    end
```

---

**service.rb model**

```
    class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :service_types
      belongs_to :tech

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_types, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    end
```

---

**service_type.rb model**

```
class ServiceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  #nested objects generated by cocoon gem

  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :tech #added 5/27 unsure if needed
end
```

---

**tech_controller.rb**

```
class TechsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @techs = Tech.all
    @customer = Customer.all
  end

  def show
    @tech = Tech.find(params[:id])
    @services = @tech.services.all    
  end

  def new
    #@appointment = Appointment.new
  end

  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:id])
    #@appointment.booked_service = @tech.first.services.first.name - the vars below are just a mickey mouse hacked up example of the value I'm trying to obtain.
    @@appointment.booked_type = @tech.first.services.first.service_types.first.name
    @@appointment.booked_price = @tech.first.services.first.service_types.price
    #...etc
    #...etc
    #...etc

    @appointment.save
    redirect_to @appointment
  end

  def edit
  end  

  def destroy
  end

private

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def appointment_params
    params.require(:appointment).permit(:booked_service, :booked_type, :booked_type_time_length, :booked_price, :customer_id, :tech_id)
    #params.require(:appointment).permit(:booked_service => :service, :booked_type, :booked_type_time_length, :booked_price, :customer_id, :tech_id)
  end
 end
```

---

**show.html.erb**

```
 <tbody>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= service.name %></td>
        <td>
          <table>
             <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Time</th>
               <th>Price</th>
               <th>Book Appointment</th>
             </tr>
             <%service.service_types.each do |service_type|%>
               <tr>
                <td><%= service_type.name %></td>
                <td><%= service_type.time %></td>
                <td><%= service_type.price %></td>
                <td><%= button_to 'Book', action: 'create' %></td>
               </tr>
             <%end%> 
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

---

**appointment view**

```
<h2>Thank you for booking your appointment!</h2>

 <b>Service:</b> <%= @appointment.id %><br>
 <b>Your Booked Service:</b> <%= @appointment.booked_service %><br>
 <b>Type selected:</b> <%= @appointment.booked_type %><br>
 <b>Length of service:</b> <%= @appointment.booked_type_time_length %><br>
 <b>Service Price:</b> <%= @appointment.booked_price %><br>
 <b>Service:</b> <%= @appointment.customer_id %><br>
 <b>Your Tech:</b> <%= @appointment.tech_id %>
```

---

Service (contains data with a list of services main categories)

```
mysql> describe services;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tech_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `tech_id` references a record in the `tech` db

ServiceType (from the cocoon gem which allows me to create nested service types with several custom attributes)

```
mysql> describe service_types;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| decimal     | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| service_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `service_id` references a record in the `services` db

---

> **Edit:** Added error below after *Button* is clicked - 5/29 - 2:38AM

The error that's returned is:

```
Couldn't find Tech with 'id'=
```

> @service_type = Tech.find(params[:tech])

---

Please let me know if further details are required.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `has_many :service_types    ` is this really a through relationship? eg Tech `has_many  :service_types, :through => :services` or is a service_type actually the Class name of an actual Service ?

Comment: `has_many :service_types` is not a through relationship. The only through relationship is with the `Appointment` model. `service_type` is the name derived from the `ServiceType` class. `service_types` object are generated from within the `Service` class (`services`) using the `Cocoon` gem.

Comment: @captainawesome : Do you create an appointment when a user clicks on Book button and then show the appointment created view page? Also, is tech already associated with survice_type? or does it have to be associated when you create an appointment?

Comment: @Surya : The _Book_ button is supposed to execute the `create` action which if saved, then go to the _Appointment_ page where it would display values. The association is `tech` > `service > `service_type`. There would be no `service_type` if there was no `service`. There would be no `service` if there was no `tech`. One could look at it like a Mechanic (`tech`) who specializes in Brakes (`service`) which has many `service_types` rotors, brake pads, brake lines, drums, etc...

Comment: @Surya : Also... The _Appointment_  isn't all that necessary, I really use it to display the results. The only direct association is with `customers` < = > `appointments` (join table) <=> `techs`.

Comment: The line you say raises an error doesn't appear to be in code you've posted. I also find it odd that the techcontroller appears to be creating appointments (although it looks like the call to Appointment.new would blow up)

Comment: @FrederickCheung: My apologies but I am very new to rails. The error appears from `/appointment`.

/root (`home_controller` and `index.html.erb`) = shows all the list of the techs (I should move `tech` index)

/techs/1 = Page for tech selected

/techs/1 = If one were to click the _Book_ button, it would instantiate a new `Appointment` object => assign values to the `@appointment.???` => `appointment.save`

Comment: I was under the impression you can instantiate an object with `@appointment = Appointment.new` from within `Tech` class? If this is not the case, then please pardon my misunderstanding. Looks like I have some reconstructing to do.

Comment: You can instantiate any object from anywhere but it is usual for FooController to create instances of Foo